# Numpy-like slicing in Julia

Tags: python, arrays, julia

In Python/Numpy I can slice arrays in this form:

```
arr = np.ones((3,4,5))
arr[2]
```

and the shape will be maintained:

```
(arr[2]).shape # prints (4, 5)
```

Which means that, if I want to keep the shape of the array, the following code works for N-dimensional arrays

```
arr = np.ones((3,4,5,2,2))
(arr[2]).shape # prints (4, 5, 2, 2)
```

This is great if I want to write functions that work for N-dim arrays preserving their output.

In Julia, however, the same action does not preserve the structure:

```
arr = ones(3,4,5)
size(arr[3]) # prints () (0-dimensinoal)
size(arr[3,:]) # prints (20,)
```

because of partial linear indexing. So if want to keep the original dimensions I need to write `arr[3,:,:]`, which only works for 3D arrays. If I want a 4D array I would have to use `arr[3,:,:,:]` and so on. The code isn't general.

Furthermore, when you get to array that are 5 dimensions or more (which is the case I'm working with now) this notation gets extremely cumbersome.

Is there any way I can write code like I do in Python and make it general? I couldn't even think of a nice clean way with reshape, let alone a way that's as clean as Python.

Comment: Not sure if it is best but you can use `arr[3, axes(arr)[2:end]...]`. Or in general store result of `axes` and then modify whatever dimension you would need. This function is present since Julia 0.7.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I thought 0.7 wasn't out yet. I'm trying it on my 0.6.2 and indeed it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that in Python the shape is only preserved if you slice the first dimension of the array. In Julia you can use `slicedim(A, d, i)` to slice dimension `d` of array `A` at index `i`.

Comment: No, you can also slice other dimensions. In numpy you don't need trailing `:`. That's it.

Comment: Did I say you couldn't slice other dimensions in Python @Kiuhnm?

Comment: I was referring to shape preservation, @juliohm. The first sentence in your answer is false. If `x` is 2x3x4x5, then `x[:,0]` is 2x4x5.

Comment: Ok, so shape preservation is another issue. From your previous comment you affirmed that one could slice other dimensions, and I never said that was not the case. Regarding shape preservation that may have changed in recent versions of Python, I am not sure. I am not using Python these days.